# cakephp saving chekbox value to database

Tags: forms, model, cakephp-2.0

```
id  int(11)
label1  varchar(10)
label2  varchar(10)
label3  varchar(10)
```

via cake bake i create model controller and view.

Now in view i want to create form using checkbox.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Check'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Check'); ?></legend>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('Check', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => array(
            'label1' => 'label1',
            'label2' => 'label2',
            'label3' => 'label3'
    )
    ));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

But i cant save data to my database. Is it possible to write text via checkbox to database ?
I read that checkbox can be only 1 or 0 to work. So i think about function beforeValidate in my model but i don't know how can i write it. Any one can help in that matter ?

Regards

Comment: $this->Form->input('Check') Are you sure in database its named as Check???

Comment: possible duplicate question. check this[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167275/cakephp-submitting-a-multiple-checkbox-input-into-the-database

Answer (score 0):

What do you do in the action of controller? Try:

```
$this->Check->save($this->request->data);
```

If using this method and data is not saved, it's probably that your checkbox has no value. Try to put `value = "1"` in the checkbox.